# Order of operations in Typescript assignment using || and array .find

Tags: typescript, variable-assignment, short-circuit-evaluation

I am wanting to make sure that the operations in my assignment occur in a specific order. I am assuming it is in the order I listed below, but I have not been able to find documentation on typescript that confirms/denies this.

```js
    const currentFreak =
      this.allFreaks.find(freak => freak.id === currentFreakId) ||
      this.allFreaks.find(freak => freak.Active) ||
      this.allFreaks.find(freak => freak.defaultFreakId);
```

Am I correct in assuming the above is executed in order, using short circuit logic?  The documentation I found at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining looks ambiguious on this specific topic in my reading of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it behaves as well as in javascript, so yes it follows short circuit logic. if there is a freak whose `freak.id === currentFreakId` the second `.find` method won't be called.